# ntlk TypeError: expected string or bytes-like

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, nltk-book

When I tried to use sent_tokenize from nltk package, I have TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Here is my code:

```
import ntlk
from ntlk.book import *  
from ntlk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

print(sent_tokenize(text9))
```

Can you help me out ? Thank a lot

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `text9`???

Comment: text9 is a book from nltk book. Basically, it's called The Man who was Thursday by G.K.Chesterton 1908

Comment: Right. This is why you shouldn't use `from <whatever> import *`. In any event, I don't know what a "book" is, but clearly, it isn't a `str` or `bytes` object. So convert it to that.

Comment: I suspect it already comes processed, so it may even have a `tokens` attribute or something like that.